# Crystal Reports will not allow me to select database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Hi I'm trying to create a report and link it to be my database within Visual Studio 2010 but when I try to make the OLE DB (ADO) connection the database does not appear within the Connection Information (Server, UserID, Password and **Database**) and then when I manually try to type in the database I get the error message:

> Failed to open the connection. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x80004005. Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server Description: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. SQL State: 08001. Native Error:17 [Database Vendor Code:17]

The database is an MDF file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using OLE DB (ADO) connection please select the checked of Integrated Security CHECKBOX and do no enter any credentials. Hope this helps

Comment: How about if I don't want to use integrated security?